# Recaptcha fixed image size

Tags: html, css, captcha, recaptcha

Why is recaptcha image fixed in size 300x57 ? Even when customizing the div where the image is injected, the width and height of the div are overridden and set to 300x57. Of course the image can be re-sized after it's rendered, but why there are no options to generate the image the size developers would like it to be.

http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/customization.html

> reCAPTCHA will rely on the presence of HTML elements with the following IDs to display the CAPTCHA to the user: An empty div with ID recaptcha_image. This is where the actual image will be placed. The div will be 300x57 pixels

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#recaptcha_image img {
    width: 200px !important;
    height: 38px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override inline css adding !important behind a css rule, even in an external file.

Answer (score 1):

Full customization with css, [demo](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/demo/custom)

```
<form method="POST" action="">



<script type="text/javascript">
                                var RecaptchaOptions = {
                                    tabindex: 1,
                                    theme: 'custom',
                                    custom_theme_widget: 'recaptcha_widget'
                                };
                            </script>
                            <div id="recaptcha_widget" style="display:none"><div id="recaptcha_image"></div>
                                <div class="recaptcha_only_if_incorrect_sol" style="color:red">Incorrect, please try again</div>
                                <span class="recaptcha_only_if_image">Enter the words above:</span>
                                <span class="recaptcha_only_if_audio">Type what you hear:</span>
                                <input type="text" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field">
                                <div class="get_another_captcha"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()">Get another CAPTCHA</a></div>
                                <div class="recaptcha_only_if_image"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type(&#39;audio&#39;)">Get an audio CAPTCHA</a></div>
                                <div class="recaptcha_only_if_audio"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type(&#39;image&#39;)">Get an image CAPTCHA</a></div>
                                <div><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.showhelp()">Help</a></div>
                                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=YourAPI"></script>
                                <noscript><iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=YourAPI" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
                                <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
                                </textarea>
                                <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"></noscript></div>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                window.onload = function() {
                                    Recaptcha.focus_response_field();
                                }
                            </script>
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 12px;"><tr><td><div><input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Submit"></div></td></tr></table></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution working for the new google Recaptcha (https://www.google.com/recaptcha/)

```
<!--adjust to your needs -->
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_sitekey" style="transform:scale(.8); margin:0 -30px">
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and effectively changed the width of the whole control not only the inner image

```
 #recaptcha_area
   {
         width: 250px !important;
         height: 38px !important;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the new version of noCaptcha Recaptcha the following works for me:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-theme="light" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"      
style="transform:scale(0.77);transform-origin:0;-webkit-transform:scale(0.77);
transform:scale(0.77);-webkit-transform-origin:0;transform-origin:0 0;"></div>
```

If you scale only still it takes the original size of the div. But the solution above fixes the blank space issue.

[Ref](https://www.geekgoddess.com/how-to-resize-the-google-nocaptcha-recaptcha/)